# Preventing errors when using mysql_real_escape_string with no active DB connection

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I have inherited a legacy system and it includes this function that is used in many, many places across the site (both front and back end).

```
function clean_text_for_db($str) {
    $str = trim($str);
    $str = stripslashes($str);
    $str = mysql_real_escape_string($str);
    return $str;
}
```

It works quite well, generally, however I noticed a bunch of errors in my apache error logs recently when the database was unavailable for a period. The errors were these:

> mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]:
>   A link to the server could not be established
>
> function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Can't connect to local MySQL
>   server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'

I understand *why* the error has occured, however what i'm not sure is how to deal with it to prevent my logs from being hit so much in the event this happens again. Considering the function is used so widely I think a `mysql_ping` before the `mysql_real_escape_string` is probably a bad idea as this would mean doing this every time the function is called and 99.9999% of the time this is unnecessary.

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` as it is deprecated. Use PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: @TimothyChoi Yes, I am aware that the `mysql_` functions have been deprecated. However, as i've said I am working on a legacy system and upgrading to PDO or MySQLi is not something that I can consider at the moment.

Comment: Ah, okay - The use of stripslashes() is kind of a hint.

Comment: Are you calling this function for non-query related context as well?

Comment: @TimothyChoi Sadly, yes. It is used not just for use with MySQL queries. I know this is wrong and makes no sense, but it is in a _lot_ of places in the system.

Comment: Because the escaping is done at the DB-side, the only option you have is to rewrite all non-query-related calls like this. Or improve your database's stability, but that's a hacky patch as well.

Comment: @TimothyChoi _Is_ that the only option, though? I was aware it was one option, however it is quite a sizeable task and bear in mind that this causes me no problems whatsoever for the vast majority of the time. Only on this rare occasion was the logs hit with a number of errors. Re-writing all the calls to this function would feel like using a sledgehammer to crack a walnut.

Comment: If your objective is to sanitize the text for other purposes (such as display), you can use alternatives like `htmlspecialchars()`. Since you didn't describe the purpose of your other non-query-related calls, I can't comment much.

Comment: @TimothyChoi I take it there's no way to check for a connection without adding an overhead for each call? I think this is my problem, really.

Comment: As far as I know, not really.

Comment: To fix the issue with logs find the place where this call fails and remove that line

Answer (score 0):

That's *really* simple. Just **get rid of this "clean_text_for_db()" function.**

And start using [PDO prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).

Comment: Check the comments with @TimothyChoi, unfortunately it's not really simple - it's actually quite an undertaking.

Comment: @crmpicco I would argue that the undertaking would be worth it in the long run though. Which DB access API to use is however irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @TimothyChoi Yes, it would absolutely be worth it in the long run. However, my question was really to find a temporary "band-aid" solution to this without a significant and very time-consuming refactor of the codebase.